# Netsuite Packing Slips (PDF/HTML)

Tags: sql, freemarker, netsuite

I'm just looking for some help, I want to display the package tracking numbers on the packing slip pdf/html templates.

Item Fulfillment > Packages > Tracking Numbers

But I can't find what the freemarker script should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
${salesorder.linkedtrackingnumbers}
```

It appears on our packing slip as if it were one of the default fields included, so apologies if I've misunderstood what you're asking.

Comment: Yes that works, only problem is it will show all the tracking numbers from all fulfillments, instead of only the tracking numbers for that fulfillment.